# Post Запрос. В чем проблема?

Tags: java, android, retrofit

Вот сам код:

```js
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.projects.test.testprojects.R;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText editText;
    private TextView translated;
    private Button translateBtm;

    private final String URL = "https://translate.yandex.kz";

    private final String KEY = "trnsl.1.1.20160721T085843Z.6a066b09d649276c.00a1c117b894e1f814b489072ec220f5bf7e3ddb";

    private Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

    private Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .build();

    private Link intf = retrofit.create(Link.class);
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        translated = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.translated);
        translateBtm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.translateBtm);

        translateBtm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Map<String,String> mapJson = new HashMap<>();
                mapJson.put("key",KEY);
                mapJson.put("text",editText.getText().toString());
                mapJson.put("lang","en-ru");

                Call<Object> call = intf.translate(mapJson);

                try {
                    Response<Object> response = call.execute();

                    Map<String,String> map = gson.fromJson(response.body().toString(),Map.class);

                    for(Map.Entry e : map.entrySet()) {
                        if(e.getKey().equals("text")) {
                            translated.setText(e.getValue().toString());
                        }
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Вот ответ:

```
07-21 09:27:08.232 25745-25745/com.projects.test.testprojects E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
        at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
        at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
        at okhttp3.Dns$1.lookup(Dns.java:39)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:172)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:138)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:80)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:178)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:129)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:98)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
        at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:109)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:124)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
        at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:170)
        at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:60)
        at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:174)
        at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall.execute(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:89)
        at com.projects.test.testprojects.activity.app.activitys.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:60)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-21 09:28:27.104 25745-25746/com.projects.test.testprojects D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 231K, 4% free 11027K/11399K, paused 10ms+0ms, total 18ms
07-21 09:32:08.904 25745-25745/com.projects.test.testprojects I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 25745 SIG: 9
```

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

значит что вы выполняете в главном потоке, запросы должны выполняться в другом потоке. Выполняйте запрос например в `AsyncTask`.